# Opening .BAT files

Tags: release-loki

I'm trying to view the info of my crypto-currency wallet, but when I tried to open up the `.bat` file with the default text editor the OS stopped responding. Is there a text editor or program to open, view, and edit `.bat` files?

Answer (score 1):

you might want to try looking at the file from a terminal ...

1. open a terminal window
2. change directory to where the file is (not req'd but my way)
3. if the file is small ... `cat {the file name}`
4. if the file is large ... `more {the file name}`

Answer (score 0):

If your file is an ordinary Windows .bat file, you can rename `*.bat` file to `*.text` and open it by any text editor.

Comment: You don't even need to rename it.

Answer (score -1):

install Leafpad from the appcenter

Comment: This answer would be more helpful if it elaborated on the program's features